# Add some top space when redirect to an anchor in another page inside my site

Tags: html, css

I have a link in my homepage that is redirecting to an specific div in another page inside my site. The problem is that when I click in the anchor, it is loading well but I have the anchor div at the really top of the window, and I have a fixed menu so I can not see the div completely well. I attach a picture to make myself clear.
[image]
Please any idea of how to display the anchor a little bit down to don't have conflicts with the top menu?

Thank you.

Comment: The anchor is in another page, not in the same one. The one that you are pointing is for an anchor in the same page.

Comment: Yet! I'm phantoming a solution with flex

Comment: What to do with my completely different and more flexible solution?

Comment: I'll still post it there, to that `duplicated` question's answers series